# What is the smallest size of pipe to which I can Weld a 1 inch pipe Perpendicular to the Axis?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, manufacturing-engineering, welding, piping

I would to know what is (or how to calculate) the size (dia) if the smallest pipe to which I can weld a 1 inch pipe from the side of the bigger pipe perpendicular to its axis (like a tee).

Comment: You can weld it to 1/8” pipe then fill the gaps... but you may want to clarify your question...

Comment: Like Solar Mike is saying It seems that you can weld whatever size you want. I think your question might be more to what is appropriate to achieve a certain level of strength in the connection?? You should clarify.

Comment: This is for a steam manifold that will have steam at max 20 Bar. So, I would like it to be strong enough to handle the stress. The outlets from the manifold will be 1 inch. There will be 8 such outlet lines. The 1 inch outlet will also have a heavy  steam valve on it (which will be provided support)

Comment: This is for a steam manifold that will have steam at max 20 Bar at around 400Degree Celsius. So, I would like it to be strong enough to handle the stresses. The outlets from the manifold will be 1 inch. There will be 8 such outlet lines. Also, each 1 inch outlet will  have a heavy  steam valve on it (which will be provided support).    |   My main doubt is, if the main line is too small a larger portion of the surface will have to be removed for each outlet, reducing its overall strength

Comment: If you are wondering the Main line size is too small for super heated steam - the flow rate is just 125 gm/min

Comment: You have crossed into ASME Boiler Code land. About any country in the world will require conformance to "code" , even if it is another countries version of the code. The code will define how close the outlets can be. What weld reinforcement and contours are required. Materials, welding , heat-treatment, non-destructive inspection , etc,etc,etc.